# Start a new thread for each user request in java

Tags: java, multithreading

In My online analytics system i want to start a new thread for each user request to start an algorithm. Also I want to keep the id of each thread for updating the progress of algorithm. I am not much familiar to threads.Kindly help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show any research efforts!

Comment: If you're not familiar with threads, you're going to get it wrong. The best thing you can do is read and learn about threading before trying to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can give you a basic idea on how to run multiple threads with a thread pool. You can start from here and defining your own handler and your pool size according to your need. You can also define the Handler as callable instead of runnable

```
public class MyTest {

@Test
public void myTest() {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    es.submit(new Handler(1));
    es.submit(new Handler(2));
    es.submit(new Handler(3));
    // block to show theads executions
    try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

}

class Handler implements Runnable {
int userId;
public Handler(int userId) {
    super();
    this.userId = userId;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("running for user:"+userId);

}

}
```